# Fixing Segmentation Fault in simple C program

Tags: c, function, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have a C program that calculates angular pair correlation, the code works fine in that. One of the lines in the code says something like

```
A = B * C
```

I made and compiled (it compiled okay) a .h C function that I want to add as a multiplication factor, i.e. I want it to do this

```
A = B * C * Y(x)
```

Now, when I run the original code I get a segmentation fault. I am suspecting it is something wrong with my .h function (I am not very familiar with C). I did not use pointers at all in my function. Basically it looks like this

```
extern double Y(double x)
{
double Z;
Z = polynomial_function_in_x;
return Z;
}
```

Comment: If it is a simple program with just one .c file, you don't need to use a .h

Comment: Where does it crash ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's just a one liner, and you're using C, the best method IMO will be to use a macro, in your header file add the following:

```
#define Y(_x) (polynomial_function_in_x(_x))
```

And in your C file you can use:

```
#include "poly_headerfile.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    A = B * C * Y(x);
    return 0;
}
```

It will be more efficient and avoids the hassle of a function, just make sure you remember to bracket your parameters!

Answer (score 0):

What is it extern ?

If it's an inline .h function, you may want it to be static:

```
static double Y(double x)
{
    double z;
    z = polynomial_function_in_x;
    return polynomial_function_in_x;
}
```

---

However, the good way to do it would be to online include the header in your .h, and the full code in a .c that gets compiled with your project.

**.h file**

```
double Y(double x);
```

**.c file**

```
double Y(double x)
{
    double z;
    z = polynomial_function_in_x;
    return polynomial_function_in_x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you need `extern` at all.

Header file should look like:

```
static inline polynomial_function(...)
{
    ...
}
```

Original file includes the header, and uses its function:

```
#include "poly_headerfile.h"

double Y(double x)
{
    return polynomial_function(x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've now turned into a static function, made a .h header file and a .c file with the code and compiled and ran everything again but I am still getting a segmentation fault. Is there anything you can think of that might be causing this? Thanks.